GFCI causing unrelated outlet on a different circut breaker to have an open neutral and it trips the GFCI
TLDR; Changed a regular duplex outlet for a new GFCI. I now have an outlet on a different circuit breaker that, when energized, shows an open neutral and trips the new GFCI immediately (nothing plugged in to it). All outlets on both breakers appeared to work fine prior to my swap of a regular outlet for a GFCI.
The story.
California house built 1984. Unknown to me until yesterday, the existing GFCI in the kitchen is only protecting some of the outlets. (My fault for assuming and not testing when I bought the house 12 years ago.)
The dishwasher is being replaced next week, and the appointment person stated they cannot install unless the dishwasher outlet is on GFCI. I said it is. After I hung up, I thought I'd better confirm, and that's when I found out otherwise. There is a separate circuit around the sink, that includes the dishwasher, that is not on GFCI.
This what I learned through flipping breakers, using an outlet tester, and NCV tester:
Circuit Breaker slot #10, 20 amp - Left of sink: Duplex outlets. Under sink: One of the outlets in a duplex, dishwasher plugs in here. Overhead sink light. Right of sink: Duplex outlets and overhead sink light switch (switch loop).
Circuit Breaker slot #11, 20 amp - Left of sink: Switch (on switch loop) for garbage disposal. Under sink: The other outlet in the duplex - garbage disposal plugs in here.
AFAICT these are the only items on the #10 and #11 breakers. (The existing GFCI is on breaker #12 and is protecting the remainder of outlets in the kitchen.)
I bought the Leviton 15amp with 20amp passthrough tamper resistant duplex GFCI to replace the existing duplex receptacle to the left of the sink. It is the first in the #10 series. https://store.leviton.com/collections/home-gfci/products/smartest-self-test-smartlockpro-slim-gfci-tamper-resistant-receptacle-with-led-indicator-15-amp-gftr1
This is the same GFCI, I have used in my rentals. Followed all instructions and wired it up. #10 circuit working well with the new GFCI, all the outlets and overhead light all test correctly with the outlet tester and all appear to work the same as before.
Then I tried to use my garbage disposal (which is on breaker #11). The new GFCI on #10 tripped immediately as soon as I turned on the disposal switch. I tested the disposal outlet, as soon as it is energized by the switch, the new GFCI on #10 trips and the outlet tester reads 30vac and open neutral.
If I turn off #10 breaker, the #11 outlet tests correctly and the disposal works.
Just to reiterate, without any GFCI, all of the outlets and switches on #10 and the disposal (#11) have seemly worked fine for 12 years.
The only thing I haven't done is examine the duplex receptacle under the sink. It's a corner double sink and the outlet is all the way in the back corner, I can barely reach to plug in. I will have to remove at least some of the undersink plumbing to be able to do anything with it.
Since we don't use the disposal much, and it runs fine plugged into an extension cord into the pre-existing GFCI, I can get by until after the new dishwasher is in.
I did read on another post about trying to find out if the new GFCI is bad, by disconnecting both load wires and testing the hot to neutral voltage of the load screws. I do have a multimeter which I'm assuming is what I need to use, but I don't know how to use it or how to do this test. I am just a homeowner who had some rentals, and have replaced like-with-like here and there.
Thank you if you can help me troubleshoot further or, hopefully, solve this? Or should I give up and call an electrician?
(EDIT: The following was posted in comments:)
The duplex outlet (now GFCI) and the garbage disposal switch share the electrical box. There are two cables entering the box, one from the top left and one from the top right. Both cables have three wires plus ground - black, white, red. The cable in upper left is "line" (confirmed line vs. load with testing per GFCI instructions). The white and black cables are attached to Line screws on GFCI. Also the ground from this cable is attached to ground on GFCI.The cable entering from upper right (next to the disposal switch) is "load", the white and black are on Load screws on GFCI. The red wires from both cables are on the disposal switch. Actually, the ground wires from both cables are clipped together, the right one is cut off near the connector and the left one as mentioned goes to the GFCI ground.
I do not know from where the garbage disposal outlet gets its wires, I assume it can't be any of the wires in the box with the switch, i.e. the wires on the GFCI. The two white and two black register nothing on NCVT when #10 breaker is off and #11 is still on. The red wires on the switch do register low voltage and the disposal outlet works correctly in that scenario.

Can you post pictures of the wiring in the boxes, especially the one where you installed the GFCI?  Can you tell whether the power for circuits 10 and 11 comes in through two separate 12/2 cables (each with one black and one white wire) or through a single 12/3 cable with a black, a red, and a white wire)?  Or if it's wires run in conduit, are there 2 separate white wires coming in vs. one white wire and 2 hot wires?  Is the garbage disposal switch in the same box as the duplex outlet on the left side?

I will get some pictures. The duplex outlet (now GFCI) and the garbage disposal switch share the electrical box. There are two cables entering the box, one from the top left and one from the top right. Both cables have three wires plus ground - black, white, red. The cable in upper left is "line" (confirmed line vs. load with testing per GFCI instructions). The white and black cables are attached to Line screws on GFCI. Also the ground from this cable is attached to ground on GFCI.The cable entering from upper right (next to the disposal switch) is "load", the white and black are on Load

screws on GFCI. The red wires from both cables are on the disposal switch. Actually, the ground wires from both cables are clipped together, the right one is cut off near the connector and the left one as mentioned goes to the GFCI ground.

I do not know from where the garbage disposal outlet gets its wires, I assume it can't be any of the wires in the box with the switch, i.e. the wires on the GFCI. The two white and two black register nothing on NCVT when #10 breaker is off and #11 is still on. The red wires on the switch do register low voltage and the disposal outlet works correctly in that scenario.

Very helpful.  Can you get a picture of the citcuit breaker box also that clearly shows the two relevant circuit breakers?

If the diagnoses in the answers below are correct, and you have the wires fed by breakers 10 and 11 as a multiwire branch circuit, (MWBC) then you have another problem after fixing the GFCI debacle: A MWBC needs to be fed from a double handle-tied (common trip?) breaker, not two separate breakers. Otherwise you could turn off one breaker and still find full power in the MWBC on the other side. Move breaker 11 to  position 12 and 12 to 11. Then replace 10 & 12 with a 240V double breaker.

Your "EDIT" confirms incorrect wiring.  Two solutions below.

I didn't make any "EDIT" - looks like someone else did, from my comments to someone else's questions.
I'm still not sure what I wired incorrectly, that you keep stating I did? If you're trying to say the mistake is that I can't use a GFCI where and how I put it, because it is on a MWBC with another circuit, then yes I understand that from the answers to my questions. I didn't know of such a thing's existence until I posted here, and as far as I can tell, I did wire the GFCI correctly had it been just it's own circuit. Or are you still saying I wired the GFCI incorrectly even so?

@Kat You can see the edits made to your question by clicking the "edited X time ago" link to the left of your name tile under your question body. I made the EDIT addition from your comments, because comments are transitory and may be deleted anytime.

@Triplefault Yes I know that. I was responding to jay613 's comment that I made some edits to my question after he posted.

@Triplefault RE: Your comment above, switching breakers 10/11/12 around and 240v, I am not following at all. Can you explain in more detail?

@Kat Would be happy to. Please start a new question about properly setting up a multi wire branch circuit, with pictures of inside your circuit breaker panel, and we'll see what we can do.

I don't need a general question. I thought your comment was posed as an option to my current situation, but I don't understand what introducing 240v is supposed to do? And why #12 is now involved? #12 currently has the other kitchen GFCI and its outlet string. It is separate from #10 and #11.

If one breaker shuts off one outlet in duplex outlet and other shuts down the other outlet, you most likely have Multi Wire Branch Circuit. This will mess with gfci outlets, because two lines share a neutral.
If you have place in the panel, consider using a two-pole gfci breaker and replacing the outlet with non gfci one. This will move the current-sensing device to place where it can measure both lines, so it can work correctly. There may or may not be a compatible breaker for your panel - best check with your electrician.

There is nothing wrong with GFCI on MWBC.  OP has made a wiring error.  Probably disposal neutral connected to GFCI Load terminal.

@jay613 The GFCI and downstream outlets all test and work perfectly, same as before the GFCI swap. Can you provide me details on what I have wired incorrectly? I thought the GFCI wouldn't test or work correctly if it was wired wrong?

@Thomas I think I may end up with what you wrote. Doing that will leave the garbage disposal on its own circuit from the dishwasher, lights, and outlets, yet offer protection to all. I am not comfortable with doing anything in the panel so I will call an electrician. It's a newer panel (12 years old). The two 20amp breakers in question are next to each other. There is an unrelated two-pole 20/20amp breaker a few slots down so I know that's possible. So I'm hopeful a two pole GFCI will be available for my panel.

@Thomas Electrician came to same conclusion, installed 2-pole GFCI circuit breaker and of course removed outlet GFCI. All good here. Thank you

[ Changed answer significantly after understanding the question properly ]
The most practical way to provide all the GFCI protection required in your kitchen is by installing a two-pole GFCI breaker.
The breaker will protect the switch itself, which is the thing you are most commonly touching with wet hands, and the outlet next to it which is presumably near the sink.  That's important.  And it will also protect the dishwasher and disposal. which are on different sides of an MWBC circuit in further downstream boxes.   You could do all this with GFCI outlets everywhere .. one in this box, one for the dishwasher, one for the disposal, etc.  Even then, with three or more GFCI devices, the switch still won't be protected.
Short of recabling your kitchen, a two-pole GFCI breaker is the only way.  It will protect everything on this circuit.

After better understanding the question I changed the answer significantly and deleted all earlier comments.

Thank you, that is also what @Thomas proposed initially. I have watched videos and though possibly DIY I'm just not comfortable making changes in the panel. I'll call an electrician.

From your description in the comments of how the wires are connected, it is likely that the circuits of breaker slots #10 and #11 form a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit (MWBC), which has a shared neutral.
MWBC circuits do not play nicely with GFCI outlets because of the shared neutral. The GFCI you installed checks how much current is flowing through the black and white wires you connected to the LINE terminals. If that amount of current differs by more than 6mA, then the GFCI trips.
The problem with the MWBC is that your garbage disposal draws current through the red wire and returns it through the white one. The GFCI only sees the current through the white wire and concludes that there it a fault in the circuit.
To fix this problem, you have to run a new 12/2 cable from the box with the GFCI and disposal switch to the box with the outlet that your garbage disposal connects to.
Connect the white wires of the incoming cable (LINE), the new cable and a pigtail to the line side of the GFCI. Connect the black wire of the new cable to the disposal switch instead of the red wire of the LOAD cable. This way, the current drawn by the disposal unit is not seen by the GFCI.

I'd like to understand your suggestion, but it is not complete enough for me. Assuming I can fish a new 12/2 cable between the box with the GFCI and the disposal switch, and the disposal outlet. I'd pigtail the Line white and new 12/2 white together onto the GFCI Line white screw. I'd swap the red wire on the Load screw of the switch for the new 12/2 black. I assume the Load red wire is now unused? And what do I wire on the other end (the disposal outlet)?

@Kat, the load red wire would become unused and is besf capped off. At the disposal outlet, you connect the black and white of the new cable. The existing wies become unused and should be capped off (individually)

Sorry, I still can't visualize what this does or how it works. It seems like the #11 breaker becomes unused and the garbage disposal goes on to the #10 breaker? I am trying to make a diagram but not having success. Is it possible you can share a diagram?
